# How to mount remote samba share from local host with multiple groups?

Tags: linux, mount, user-accounts, samba, cifs

I am using mount.cifs to mount a remote samba share (both client and server are Ubuntu server 8.04) like this:

```
mount.cifs //sambaserver/samba /mountpath -o credentials=/path/.credentials,uid=someuser,gid=1000

$ cat .credentials
username=user
password=password
```

I mounted a user from local system with username and password with mount.cifs but the problem is that the user is part of multiple groups on the remote system and with mount.cifs I can only specify one gid. Is there a way to specify all the gids that the remote user has?

Is there a way to:

1. Mount the remote samba with multiple groups on the local system?
2. Browse the mount from 1) with the terminal since I want to pass some files from samba
   as arguments to local programs.

Other solutions would be:

- nautilus sftp:// which runs through gvfs; but the newer gnome does not write to disk the ~/.gvfs anymore so I can't browse it in terminal.
- And the last solution would be NFS but that means that I have to synchronize the uids and gids on the local system with the ones from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It should do it by default. Have you checked the ACL with `getfacl`?

Answer (score -1):

Check for multiuser mount with samba.

https://educatorhome.com/provide-network-shares-suitable-for-group-collaboration/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Glorfindel.  This link contains complete step by step tutorial along vid video demonstration.. I don't think there is any other better way to answer.

Comment: There IS a better way to answer, and it is what @Glorfindel suggests. Your answer may be great, but if the link or content changes, your answer will become useless, which is not what we (or you) want to happen. Keep the link for attribution, but you must post ALL of the information relevant to the answer in this answer here, otherwise your answer will be closed as being "Link-Only".

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. My future answers will follow this pattern

Comment: @AsifShabbir You need to fix **this** answer as well as any future answers.